# vue Failed to cpmpile with 3 errors

Tags: vue.js

Failed to compile with 3 errors

These dependencies were not found:

- @/assets/styles/.scss in ./src/main.js
- @/components//Doc in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/layout/components/Navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
- @/components//Git in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/layout/components/Navbar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install them, you can run: npm install --save @/assets/styles/.scss @/components//Doc @/components//Git

npm install

npm install --registry=https://registry.npmmirror.com

npm run dev

Comment: Please share the main.js and vite.config.js